# Back to login screen when using Xubuntu desktop

Tags: 12.10, xfce, login-screen

I've installed lot of DE's, including `xubuntu-desktop`. Then I decided to uninstall all except `xubuntu-desktop`. Now, when I login to Ubuntu using either XFCE or Xubuntu session, a few seconds after showing the desktop, I'm returned to the login screen automatically.

Specifications:

- Ubuntu 12.10 using Wubi
- Acer Aspire V5-471
- Intel HD Graphics 3000
- Enabled composite in XFCE (not with compiz)

*edit:* Last thing I done in XFCE session before that thing happens is adds item in panel and modifying it's original menu.

*edit 2:* Removing unneeded packages solves my problem, but when changing themes it went back again to `lightdm`.

*edit 3:* Just logged again, and back again to `lightdm` with some startup programs like `xterm`, `java` and `screenlets`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like xfwm4 is messed up..Try this

At the login screen, switch to a terminal with `control-alt-F1` and login
Type the following `rm -R ~/.cache/sessions/*` type `logout` switch back to the login screen with `control-alt-F7` try to log in.